# Question on Potential Relationship between Mertens Function and Perfect Number Counting Function

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers, mobius-function

This question assumes the following definitions where $M(x)$ is the Mertens function and $f(x)$ is the perfect number counting function. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerfectNumberQ.html?q=PerfectNumberQ) for more information on the Wolfram Language PerfectNumberQ[n] function referenced below.

**(1)** $\quad M(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\mu(n)$

**(2)** $\quad f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}a(n)\,,\qquad a(n)=
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \text{PerfectNumberQ}[n] \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$

I've verified the following relationship for the first 1,000,000 positive integer values of $x$. See https://oeis.org/A080225 for more information on the $b(n)$ coefficient function referenced and defined below.

**(3)** $\quad f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}b(n)\,M(\frac{x}{n})\,,\qquad b(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}a(d)$

> **Question**: Can the relationship illustrated in (3) above be proved (or disproved)?

See the following links for more information on perfect numbers.

- [Wikipedia Article: Perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)
- [Weisstein, Eric W. "Perfect Number." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectNumber.html)
- https://oeis.org/A000396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really the basics of Dirichlet convolution.

$$b(n) = \sum_{d | n} a(d), \qquad \sum_{d | n} \mu(n/d)b(d) = a(n)$$
$$f(x)  =\sum_{n \le x} a(n) =  \sum_{n \le x} \sum_{d | n} \mu(n/d)b(d)= \sum_{n \le x}  \sum_{dm = n}b(d) \mu(m)\\= \sum_{dm\le x} b(d) \mu(m)= \sum_{d \le x} b(d) \sum_{m\le x/d} \mu(m) $$